# How to 301 redirect when a user's IP address is not authorized?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I'm setting up a development server on one of my subdomains.  I'm controlling access to the site using the visitor's IP address.  When I see a visitor that is not authorized, I want to 301 redirect them to the main website.  I've got a temporary solution using the following .htaccess directive:

```
ErrorDocument 403 http://www.mymainsite.com/
```

But my understanding is that's a 302 redirect.  I want to do a 301.

In looking for a solution I came across the following:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} !=""
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.mymainsite.com [R=301,L]
```

It does not appear to be working, however.  Just for reference, I'm blocking on IP, not a login, so this are my settings:

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
Allow from 12.2.120.233
```

Anyone know how to get this working as a 301?

Comment: "When I see a visitor that is not authorized, I want to 301 redirect" are you sure? Firstly you should not use ip address as an authentication mechanism, and secondly, is it really your intention to ensure that device never accesses your site again? (Browsers will cache 301 redirects indefinitely). Since a browser will not issue an auhorization prompt and request header, the solution you found will prevent everyone from ever accessing the authenticated site unless they previously visited it and supplied valid credentials before this config was applied.

Comment: ...and the 403 handler is **not** a redirect of any kind.

Comment: Our developers have access to the site based on their IP addresses (and .htpasswd logins as well).  Any other visitors including bots should be 301'ed to the main site.  We don't want them to have visibility of the development site and just want to bounce all traffic to the live site.  The 403 is sending the visitor to a completely different domain.  When I do a redirect check on that URL, it shows up as a 302 redirect.  I have verified that it works correctly on my phone by putting it on and off the local network.  Browser caching is not an issue.

Comment: This is not the right way to solve the problem (nor the way to run a dev environment). What the right solution is depends on a lot of considerations we don't know about (location, asset value, security model....)